# An internal error occurred during: "Execute Debug Command"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

[image]

> An internal error occurred during: "Execute Debug Command". Unable to
> make field private final long java.lang.ProcessImpl.handle accessible:
> module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module
> @27d81e67

Hi, I am getting this error whenever I am trying to terminate a project in Eclipse or when I try to relaunch a project.

My eclipse version is Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) & I am using Java version 11.

I found the below log details in About Eclipse--> View log Error

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2022-02-08 16:13:15.042
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Execute Debug Command".
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final long java.lang.ProcessImpl.handle accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @27d81e67
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:177)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:171)
    at org.jboss.tools.quarkus.core.launch.RuntimeProcessWithJVMAttach.preTerminate(RuntimeProcessWithJVMAttach.java:73)
    at org.jboss.tools.quarkus.core.launch.RuntimeProcessWithJVMAttach.terminate(RuntimeProcessWithJVMAttach.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.commands.TerminateCommand.execute(TerminateCommand.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.commands.ForEachCommand.doExecute(ForEachCommand.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.commands.AbstractDebugCommand$1.run(AbstractDebugCommand.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: Do you have any compilation errors in the project?

Comment: What are you trying to run?

Comment: Yes Just a port error that 8080 seems to be in use by another process. But before that also I was getting the same error when i try to terminate the project( in console--> clicking the red button).

Comment: I am running a Quarkus Application

Comment: Something is trying to mess around with ProcessImpl but this no longer works in newer versions of Java. I don't see any bug reports for this in the Eclipse bugzilla. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: I have provided the Log message, please kindly check

Comment: The log shows it is JBoss / Quarkus that is causing the problem, not Eclipse. Look for updated code from them.

Comment: @SonaliDash Any chance, you got solution? I'm facing same issue.